# How to plot a large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is what my dataframe looks like :
Date,Sales, location

There are a total of 20k entries. Dates are from 2016-2019. I need to have dates on x axis and sales on y axis. This is how I have done it

```
df1.plot(x="DATE", y=["Total_Sales"], kind="bar", figsize=(1000,20))
```

Unfortunately even with this the dates aren't clearly visible. How do I make sure that they are pretty plotted? Is there a way to create bins or something.

Edit: output

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 382 entries, 0 to 18116
Data columns (total 5 columns):
DATE           382 non-null object
Total_Sales    358 non-null float64
Total_Sum      24 non-null float64
Total_Units    382 non-null int64
locationkey    382 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 17.9+ KB
```

Edit: Maybe I can divide it into years stacked on top of each other. So, for instance, Jan to Dec 16 will be the first and then succeeding years will be plotted with it. How do I do that?

Comment: figsize is in inches, 1000 inches are 25m. That is no useful figure size. I suspect your problem comes from not converting the strings to actual dates.

Comment: Can you show you us the output of `df1.head()` and `df1.info()` please?

Comment: I think you need to first "group by" your sales data. Not shure how is your data organized but I think it would be better to group it by months or semester and then plot it, so it can be more readable.

Comment: @benjad doesn't work that way either since it is alot of data

Comment: As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest said I believe you can solve your issue by turning your `DATE` column into a datetime object. You can try with `df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'])` you might have to pass `format=''` depending on how your dates are formatted.

Comment: @CeliusStingher this is what date looks like : 1/1/2016  12:00:00 AM

Comment: @CeliusStingher Same issue

Comment: Did you also fix the `figsize` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do this:

```
df.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
df = df.set_index('DATE')
```

Now the dataframe's *index* is the date. This is very convenient. For example, you can do:

```
df.resample('Y').sum()
```

You should also be able to plot:

```
df.Total_Sales.plot()
```

And `pandas` will take care of making the x-axis linear in time, formatting the date, etc.